# validators for bulk image upload

Tags: django, django-models

I have a feature that allows users to upload multiple images. I want to setup a validator to only allow images that are under 3MB.

```
def validate_image_bulk(images):

    file_size = images.file.size
    if file_size > settings.MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE:
        raise ValidationError(f'Cover Image {images} is too large 3mb max')
```

How can I get a list of the images being uploaded and validate them at the same time. In a view I could do something like `request.FILES.getlist('images')` is there something similar like this?

Answer (score 1):

## Things to understand

1. `images` in `validate_image_bulk` is a single file (that's what `models.ImageField` handles and that's why you do `images.file.size` same as `image.file.size` in `validate_image`).
2. `validate_image_bulk` is always called with the same file (specifically, the last file) from `PostImagesForm(request.POST, request.FILES)`.
3. `for x in images` in `validate_images_bulk` loops over the bytes, not multiple images.

## Solution

Do `PostImagesForm(request.POST, {'images': image})` instead:

```py
post_images_forms = []
for image in request.FILES.getlist('images'):
    post_images_form = PostImagesForm(request.POST, {'images': image})
    if not post_images_form.is_valid():
        break
    post_images_forms.append(post_images_form)
else:  # if len(post_images_forms) == len(request.FILES.getlist('images')):
    for post_images_form in post_images_forms:
        instance = post_images_form.save(commit=False)
        instance.post_id = PostFormID.id
        instance.save()
```

### Recommendations for sanity

1. Rename `images` to `image`.
2. Discard `validate_images_bulk` since it's functionally same as `validate_image`.

```py
class PostImages(models.Model):
    # images = models.ImageField(validators=[validate_image_bulk])  # Change this
    image = models.ImageField(validators=[validate_image])          # to this
```

Answer (score 1):

crate an validator.py inside your app:

**validator.py**

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


def validate_file_size(value):
    filesize = value.size
    
    if filesize > 3145728:  #3 * 1024 * 1024
       raise ValidationError('The maximum file size that can be uploaded is 3MB')
    else:
      return value
```

your models.py

```
from .validator import *
from django.core.validators import FileExtensionValidator #if you also want to use file type Validator

class mymodel(models.Model)
      image = models.ImageField(upload_to='blog/images/',validators=[validate_file_size,FileExtensionValidator( ['png','jpg'] )],blank=True,null=True) #only accept 'png' and 'jpg' image.
```

You can check django documentation for [FileExtensionValidator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/validators/#fileextensionvalidator)